# Need to call this php function inside a modal window from text widget

Tags: custom-field, twitter-bootstrap

Need to call this php function inside a modal window from sidebar text widget

```
<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'link', true ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several examples on the net, however I use this:

```
<?php

//functions.php

add_filter( 'widget_text', 'php_parser', 100 );
function php_parser( $html ){
 if( strpos( $html, "<"."?php" ) !== false ){
      ob_start();
      eval( "?".">".$html );
      $html = ob_get_contents();
      ob_end_clean();
 }
 return $html;   
}

?>
```

Comment: Oh great, can you give me the exact code for the above one. I mean    <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'link', true ); ?> sorry im a begineer.

Comment: You can use it as it is : ), you need to copy the snippet to your functions.php

Comment: Oh ok,,you mean i need to copy that code to functions.php and then call the php function in text widget right?

Comment: Yes you're right

Comment: Does the code work ?

Comment: hope something is working :) Great :)

Comment: But im calling it in a modal window its not showing anything output. Actually it should echo the link, but not able to see any link

Comment: where is the code of modal window? Are you putting it in the text widget? can you post this code please?

Comment: Yes im putting in text widget.
    `<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
<div class="modal-header">
<h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal window</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
 
<p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,’link’,true); ?></p>
<p><?php echo $code; ?></p>
<?php echo "<a href='$post->link' target='_blank'>$post->post_title</a>"; ?>

</div>
</div>
</div>`

Comment: The modal window will appear in the view single post? If yes add `global $post;` like [this](http://pastebin.com/d2mAqn55) else the solution is a little bit tricky but far from impossible.

Comment: great hope 80% is working now. But its a coupon site, so the link will change for every coupons. But after implementing this the link number is not changing. Please can you give me your mail id so that will send details about this.

Comment: Link number is showing only as 85, its not changing for every coupon post. Please let me if u require the wp and ftp access will provide the same.

Comment: Hello @user2695925 , could you give me the url, please?

Comment: Can I private message you the link?